# Troubles with opening cyrillic file path from explorer in Windws XP

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-xp, cmd, file-type

Operating system: Windows XP SP3

Trying to define commands to open some file-types from context menu or directly from explorer and having the following problem:

- standard `"C:\Program Files\SQLite ODBC Driver\sqlite3.exe" "%1"` isn't working if file is in directory that contains cyrillic (non-ASCII) characters;
- command `"C:\Program Files\SQLite ODBC Driver\sqlite3.exe" "%~s0"` isn't working because specified argument template unfortunately is only for batch files;
- variant with creating batch file with previous command is ugly and unneficient.

Is there a right or convenient way to open files with non-ASCII characters in path?
Without ugly magic I mean.

**UPDATE:**

I think that `"C:\Dir one\0016~1\file.sqlite"` format would work.

`%L` key isn't working too.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Still ugly but it mades the deal.

> ...used a command like:
>
> `short.cmd "myapp.exe" "%1"`
>
> where `short.cmd` contains the line
>
> `start %~s1 %~s2`
>
> This then converts the app name and the filename to short versions, and
>    executes as desired - but there is a command window that pops up briefly in
>    there (running the START command)

Link: [Context menu shell commands %1, %L parameters](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/context-menu-shell-commands-1-l-parameters-t421320.html)